# Find what versions of iOS an app can run on?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm fairly novice to iOS programming(well, very novice...). Anyways, before I start getting too in-depth with the coding of my app, is there a way to check which iOS versions it will run on? I'm probably missing something obvious, but I am aiming to make it run on all 4.0 devices to the most current devices. I just want to make sure I don't use a library or something that is only supported on iOS 5.0 or something.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way I can think of is to test on devices running 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll can set the “Base SDK” in your projects settings to the version of iOS that you want to target. As far as inadvertently using functionality not defined in previous iOS versions, pay attention to your warnings - It will tell you if you're using something not defined in iOS 4.

Comment: It only shows "Lastest iOS (iOS 5.1)"  Do I need to download another SDK and will that mess anything up?

Comment: Check Xcode / Preferences / Downloads and see if you can download the iOS 4 SDK and simulator.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is done more easily if you decide what iOS versions you want the app to work on before you start development. Every framework has different supported iOS versions that you will have to keep in mind while programming, for example, if you wanted to make an app that utilized the new integrated Twitter framework (iOS 5+) you would have to either set your deployment target to only iOS devices running 5.0 and above, or you could code detection to check what iOS version the device is running and in this case, roughly... if iOS >=5.0 use twitter, and if iOS < 5 don't use twitter.

Comment: Well, I am just starting.  Only thing I am really using now is storyboard, NSUrlConnection, and JSONKit.

Comment: And as I just read, storyboards aren't compatible with iOS 4, so I guess I am out of luck...  Not many people are still on iOS 4, I suppose.

Comment: There are some devices that will always be stuck on earlier versions.  The first generation iPhones and iPod touches support iOS 3.1.3 at best.  The second generation iPod touch and iPhone 3G are stuck at iOS 4.2.1.  Are these worth supporting?  Consult [this graph](http://pxldot.com/post/18754186750/ios-ebb-and-flow).  Note the disclaimers - the data are from different app developers, and may not represent the population.  Even given that, it's safe to call iOS 3 insignificant, and iOS 4 is plummeting relative to iOS 5.

Comment: The last data I've seen puts iOS 5 and above at a little over 80%. I'd still like to support 4 whenever possible, but it is definitely becoming reasonable to limit it to 5 if you have something you'd like to use. There is definitely no reason to support before 4 IMO. I think > 4 is at about 98-99% now.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Projekt --> Get Info :
There you can see the iOS version of your project. (latest ios Version)

greez